# beamer frame: overlap itemization with graphics

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I try to create a `beamer` frame, which does the following:

Show a common itemization (placed on top of the slides) interrupted by slides with graphics, that are centered in the middle of the slide. In particular the itemization should not be present on the graphic-slides.

The problem is, that my code places the itemization on top of the slides (how I want it to be), but the graphics at that line in the itemization, where the last item before the first graphics appears. I want the graphics to be centered vertically and horizontally.

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,utf8]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\onslide<1,3,6->{\item item }
\onslide<3,6->{\item item }
\onslide<6->{\item item }
\onslide<7->{\item item }
\onslide<8->{\item item }
\end{itemize}
\hspace{1cm}
\onslide<9->{$\Rightarrow$ lalala}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics<2>[width=0.8\textwidth]{PIC1.jpeg}
\includegraphics<4>[width=0.8\textwidth]{PIC2.jpeg}
\includegraphics<5>[width=0.8\textwidth]{PIC3.jpeg}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It seems rather simple, especially if you think about how simple it is in powerpoint or something like that, but I don't get it in TEX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and put your images inside `\node`s placed at the `current page.center` special anchor (`\node` is overlay aware). Compile the code twice so the images reach their final positions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,utf8]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1,3,6-> item 
\item<3,6-> item 
\item<6-> item
\item<7-> item
\item<8-> item
\end{itemize}
\hspace{1cm}
\only<9->{$\Rightarrow$ lalala}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node<2>[inner sep=0pt] 
  at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\node<4>[inner sep=0pt] 
  at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
\node<5>[inner sep=0pt] 
  at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

In some themes, (those with sidebar and headline) the current page.center anchor won't produce the placement at the center of the text area; in this case, you can use some shiftings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,utf8]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newlength\SidebarWd
\newlength\HeadHt
\setlength\SidebarWd{0.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\setlength\HeadHt{0.5\beamer@headheight}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1,3,6-> item 
\item<3,6-> item 
\item<6-> item
\item<7-> item
\item<8-> item
\end{itemize}
\hspace{1cm}
\only<9->{$\Rightarrow$ lalala}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node<2>[inner sep=0pt] 
  at ([shift={(\the\SidebarWd,-\the\HeadHt)}]current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\node<4>[inner sep=0pt] 
  at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
\node<5>[inner sep=0pt] 
  at (current page.center)
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is much of what I was looking for. One last question: the coordinates page.center places the graphic at the page's center.  That looks a bit miscentred, when using a beamer theme like Berkeley, that has additional blocks for the toc on the left side and a headline on top of each slide. Is there a possibility to get the coordinates of the center of the area without the head- and side-blocks or do I have to set this manually.

Comment: @zufall You're welcome! You can do some manual adjustments using the `shift` key for the nodes, but you can do that using the appropriate `beamer` lengths. Please see my updated answer.